# haproxy load balance based on Jenkins api

Tags: jenkins, haproxy

Using Haproxy Is it possible to load balance based on the output of a GET request to a specific url? The use case for this is load balancing between a set of jenkins machines and routing the next automated job to the least busy server.

for example I can hit this url server-1/computer/api/json?pretty&tree=busyExecutors

which gives an output like:

> {
>     "busyExecutors" : 5
>   }

in this case we have 5 busy executors.
Id like Haproxy to hit this url and assess which server is least busy and route the next job there. Does this sound possible? really the output and busyExecutors is irrelevant here im just looking for a way to get some kind of information from the jenkins servers and load balance off of that info.

I've looked into balance url_param and balance uri but neither really seem to be what im looking for. I've also tested balance leastconn and it also is not what im looking for.

If im completely off base here let me know, and if there would be a better way to go about this im all ears.

Thanks

Comment: This is something I would do inside of Jenkins, since it has the best information about what nodes and executors are available, what labels they have, and what environment each job should run in. If you want to explicitly run a build on the "least loaded" build node, you could try the [Least Load Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Least+Load+Plugin).

Comment: Thanks Christopher. Yes the least load plugin looks like it would be a good solution for most cases, but in this case I'm looking to load balance a few identical masters not slaves. I've determined this is not something Haproxy can do and am currently exploring other options. looks like gearman might be an option.